# Marginal probability density function of unordered eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, random-matrices

What does the marginal probability density function of unordered eigenvalues refer to? For example, the semi-circle law

\begin{equation}
f(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\sqrt{(4-x^2)^+}
\end{equation}
where $(x)^+=\text{max}\{0,x\}$

is the asymptotic marginal density of the unordered eigenvalues of a standard Wigner matrix under some conditions. Does this mean that $f(x)$ is the probability that any eigenvalue is equal to $x$?

Answer (score 0):

No, since the distribution is continuous and is given by certain [p.d.f.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function). The probability for each value is 0. To draw analogies with much easier setup: $\xi \sim \mathcal{U}[0, 1]$ with p.d.f. $f_{\xi}(x) = \mathbf{1}_x([0, 1])$, but the probability of uniform random variable being equal to $1/2$ is indeed not $1$.